# replacing dots in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as in the image. (the numbers are really objects). Doing `df.treasury_rate = pd.to_numeric(df.treasury_rate)`, predictably bombs. However, doing `df.replace('.', np.nan)` does not appear to get rid of the dot, so I am flummoxed. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE** `pd.to_numeric` takes an `errors` keyword, which, when set to `coerce` does the right thing, however, I am still confused as to why the `.` is not getting replaced.

**UPDATE 2** As text:

```
treasury_rate
1962-02-09 4.05
1962-02-10 4.05
1962-02-11 4.05
1962-02-12 .
1962-02-13 4.03
1962-02-14 4.03
1962-02-15 4.02 
1962-02-16 4.02
1962-02-17 4.02
1962-02-18 4.02
```

Comment: Please post your data as text, not as an image. We do not want to retype it.

Answer (score 4):

```
df.replace('\.','0', regex=True,inplace=True)
```

I think you have to give regex for '.' character to replace it.

Comment: I am confused, still - if regex is not true, why would it (pandas) interpret a dot as a regex? Seems to be a bug...

Comment: It's not a bug, as @cullzie mentions in his answer below, the important part was using the parameter inplace=True otherwise results aren't stored to the df.

Comment: @igor Rivin if regex is not true pandas interpreting it as only '.' char not as dot regex df0.replace('.','0'). where as inplace=True is just making change to your original dataframe , it works like df =df.replace('.','0')

Answer (score 3):

In this case creating a mask / subset and replacing the string literal would be better than attempting to use replace. You'll probably also want to convert your series to numeric you can also do it all in one step if you know your data is clean other than the "." character:

```
subs = df.treasury_rate == "."
df.loc[subs, 'treasure_rate'] = np.nan
# OR
df.treasury_rate = pd.to_numeric('treasury_rate', errors='coerce')
```

You could likely run the last line and have the dots replaced with `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add **inplace=True** if you want to update the df object inplace:

```
df.replace('.', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Otherwise [df.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace) returns an new dataframe which you must assign to a variable to access:

```
new_df = df.replace('.', np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given OP's dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'treasury_rate': [4.05, 4.05, 4.05, ".", 4.03, 4.03, 4.02, 4.02, 4.02, 4.0]},
                    index=[dt.datetime(1962, 2, 9), dt.datetime(1962, 2, 10), dt.datetime(1962, 2, 11), dt.datetime(1962, 2, 12), dt.datetime(1962, 2, 13), dt.datetime(1962, 2, 14), dt.datetime(1962, 2, 15), dt.datetime(1962, 2, 16), dt.datetime(1962, 2, 17), dt.datetime(1962, 2, 18)])


[Out]:
           treasury_rate
1962-02-09          4.05
1962-02-10          4.05
1962-02-11          4.05
1962-02-12             .
1962-02-13          4.03
1962-02-14          4.03
1962-02-15          4.02
1962-02-16          4.02
1962-02-17          4.02
1962-02-18           4.0
```

There are various ways one can go about replacing the dot with NaN.

1. Using regular expression (with Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html))

   ```
   import re

   df_new = df.replace(re.compile('\.'), np.nan)
   ```
2. Using a custom lambda function and [`np.nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html?highlight=numpy%20nan#numpy.nan)

   ```
   import numpy as np

   df_new = df.treasury_rate.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == '.' else x)
   ```
3. Using [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and [`np.nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html?highlight=numpy%20nan#numpy.nan)

   ```
   import numpy as np

   df_new = df.replace('.', np.nan)

   # or

   df_new = df.replace(to_replace=r'\.', value=np.nan, regex=True)
   ```

In all three cases the output is

```
            treasury_rate
1962-02-09           4.05
1962-02-10           4.05
1962-02-11           4.05
1962-02-12            NaN
1962-02-13           4.03
1962-02-14           4.03
1962-02-15           4.02
1962-02-16           4.02
1962-02-17           4.02
1962-02-18           4.00
```

---

**Notes:**

- If one wants to do the operations on the same dataframe, one can use `inplace=True` such as

  ```
  df.replace(re.compile('\.'), np.nan)
  ```
- Pandas has their own null value. So, instead of [`np.nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html?highlight=numpy%20nan#numpy.nan), one might want to use [`pd.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values). For more information on the difference between those two: [pd.NA vs np.nan for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60115806/7109869)
  If one uses `pd.NA`, the output would be

  ```
             treasury_rate
  1962-02-09          4.05
  1962-02-10          4.05
  1962-02-11          4.05
  1962-02-12          <NA>
  1962-02-13          4.03
  1962-02-14          4.03
  1962-02-15          4.02
  1962-02-16          4.02
  1962-02-17          4.02
  1962-02-18           4.0
  ```
- There are strong opinions on using `.apply`. If one wants to read some: [When should I (not) want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/7109869)