# Why does pandas allow you to replace 0 with np.nan(float) but pd.NA is not allowed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

this works -> `df = df.replace(0, np.nan)`

this does not -> `df = df.replace(0, pd.NA)`

It works fine in Jupyter notebooks, just not when run as a .py file

Sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({0, 0, 0, 0})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({0, 0, 0, 0})

df1.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df2.replace(0, pd.NA, inplace=True)

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

This is the end of the error message when thrown:

```
File site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\base.py", line 312, in is_dtype
    if isinstance(dtype, (ABCSeries, ABCIndex, ABCDataFrame, np.dtype)):
  File "lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\generic.py", line 47, in _instancecheck
    return _check(inst) and not isinstance(inst, type)
  File "lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\generic.py", line 41, in _check
    return getattr(inst, attr, "_typ") in comp
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Pandas version - 1.5.1
Numpy version - 1.23.4
Python version - 3.10

Comment: Both work for me

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115806/pd-na-vs-np-nan-for-pandas)

Comment: Could you please add some detailes, such as your Pandas version and how it looks on your side? Is there some error message or the kernel (if you use Jupyter or IPython) just crashes?

Comment: Pandas version - 1.5.1

Numpy version - 1.23.4 

Python version - 3.10

Comment: It works fine in Jupyter notebooks, just not when run as a .py file