# how to count missing values that are not the regular missing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a Dataframe that have some null values, but also other entries that I should count as missing. The forms of missing that I want to take into account are:

- The normal null value from pandas
- The string N/A
- 0.0
- "-"

I want to identify the percentage of missing values per column.

I tried this

```
   # Total null values
    mis_val = df.isnull().sum()
    
    # N/A values
    mis_val = mis_val+(df=='N/A').sum()
    
    # Percentage of total data
    mis_val_percent = 100 * mis_val / len(df)
```

But the second line of code doesn't seem to do what I expected. I wanted it to count the number of 'N/A' per column

Comment: This should work. Can you edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using `isin([])`

```
mis_val = df.Data.isin([pd.NA, np.nan, None, '-', 'N/A', 0]).sum()
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [1, 2, 3, 'text', pd.NA, 5, 0, 4, '-', 12, 'N/A', 20, np.nan]})
mis_val = df.Data.isin([pd.NA, np.nan, None, '-', 'N/A', 0]).sum()
mis_val_percent = 100 * mis_val / df.size
print(f'Missed values rate is {mis_val_percent:.02f}%')
```

```
Missed values rate is 38.46%
```

Side note. About using  [pd.NA vs np.nan for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115806/pd-na-vs-np-nan-for-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

here is one way about it

```
# define regex pattern on values that you like treated as null
# remember to escape the regex character

# defined N/A, 0.0, and - : /, . and - are all escaped with \
# each patter is separated with |
pat = 'N\/A|0\.0|\-'

# replace values defined in pat with np.nan
# check if its null and take the sum

df['col'].replace(pat, np.nan, regex=True).isna().sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the missing forms are always the same, here is another way of doing it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'col1':[10.0,20.0,np.nan,'N/A',0,25],
        'col2':[0,np.nan,'N/A','N/A','','-']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# The 4 "forms of missing": 
missing_1 = (df=='N/A').sum()
missing_2 = df.isna().sum()
missing_3 = df.isnull().sum()
missing_4 = (df=='-').sum()

mis_val_percent =100*(missing_1+missing_2+missing_3+missing_4)/len(df)
print(mis_val_percent)
```

outputs:

```py
col1    50.000000
col2    83.333333
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want count N/A in particular column:

```
df["Col_name"].isna().sum()
```

If you want count N/A in full data frame:

```
df.isna().sum().sum()
```

Comment: This does not answer OPs question