# pd.DataFrame.eq() not returning the expected ouput

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I am working with the [ames-iowa-housing-dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/marcopale/housing) and tried to find the null values in the categorical columns usign the the following code:

```
(data
  .select_dtypes('string')
  .eq('NA')   # equals an empty string
  .mean(axis='rows')
  .mul(100)
  .pipe(lambda ser: ser[ser > 0])
)
```

It outputs an empty series:

```
Series([], dtype: double[pyarrow])
```

It shouldn't be this as the 'Alley' column contains NA values.

I tried replacing the empty string('') with None, but it didn't work.

Comment: Isn't this looking for a string which is literally 'NA'? It seems like it would be more appropriate to replace `.eq('NA')` with `.isna()`.

Comment: @NickODell Yes `.isna()` is right to use. But, there are two null dtypes the dataframe *data* is showing : `NA` and `<NA>`. If I want the two null dtypes separately, how can I do that?

Comment: are you looking for empty string, as `''` ? then `.eq('NA')` `to .eq('')'

Comment: maybe this will help with `NA` and `<NA>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115806/pd-na-vs-np-nan-for-pandas

Comment: @nisakova I got it! `pd.NA == pd.NA` is just `pd.NA` and not a boolean. So, the `.eq()` method is not gonna work! Thanks to point out,

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. The `mean` call may not work. Are you trying to impute the missing strings? Count the missings? A sample data input and desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
for col in categorical_cols:
    null_values = df[col].isnull().sum()
    print(f"Column '{col}' has {null_values} null value(s).")
```

with pandas it would show you all NA and count.